# JSON Parsing Decodable in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift4

With the json below, is it possible to get those keys under "fields" and print out one by one using for loop. (path, public_key, icon, name, description)

```
{
"fields" : {
  "path" : { "type" : "text", "source" : "path" },
  "public_key" : { "type" : "text", "source" : "public_key" },
  "icon" : { "type" : "image", "source" : "icon" },
  "name" : { "type" : "text", "source" : "name" },
  "description" : { "type" : "text", "source" : "description" }
},
"parName" : "myapps",
"method" : 103,
"table" : "appslist",
"callBackID" : "25b4599a-eead-6f6c-894e-e4de05b1364b"
}
```

My object model

```
struct params: Decodable {
    let fields: fields?    
    let parName: String?
    let method: Int?
    let table: String?
    let callBackID: String?
}

struct fields: Decodable {
    let name: properties?
    let description: properties?
    let public_key: properties?
    let path: properties?
    let icon: properties?
    let imagelist: properties?
    let templatepath: properties?
    let thumbnail: properties?
}

struct properties: Decodable {
    let source: String?
    let type: String?
}
```

Comment: Try this: https://grokswift.com/json-swift-4/   and another one: https://medium.com/@YuriD4/json-encoding-and-decoding-swift-4-c106d7b3c2bd

Comment: Thanks @FaysalAhmed, I will review those links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a loop and the keys are dynamic decode the fields as `[String:Properties]`

First of all declare the structs with capitalized names and declare only those properties as optional which can be `nil`.

```
struct Params: Decodable {
    let fields: [String:Properties]
    let parName: String
    let method: Int
    let table: String
    let callBackID: String
}

struct Properties: Decodable {
    let source: String
    let type: String
}
```

Then decode the JSON, define an array of key paths and enumerate the array (`data` is the `Data` instance representing the JSON)

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Params.self, from: data)
    let fields = result.fields
    for (key, _) in result.fields {
        print(key)
    }
} catch {
    print("error: ", error)
}
```

Comment: Hi Sir, thank you for your response. I think my question is not clear. With this line Fields.name it will print the "type":"value", "source":"value". What I wanted to do is print the "keys" under "fields" dynamically. In the json i provide "fields" has object "name", "description", "public_key", "path", "icon" and in some case this will have another object like "id".  Sorry for my english.

Comment: print(Params.fields) maybe this output "fields":"name", "fields":"description", etc...

Comment: The `Decodable` protocol is based on concrete static types. If the keys are dynamic use traditional `JSONSerialization`. Or decode the object as `[String:Properties]` and enumerate the dictionary. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. this is the one that I've been looking for. :D